# How to restrict views to User groups?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 2.0 .
I have created user groups now I want to restrict views using User Groups.
Which is the best way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 9):

If you want only users who belong to a specific group to be able to access the `view`, then you can use `UserPassesTestMixin`.
In the example below, a certain user can access the view only if he belongs to the `YourGroupName` group (I named it in this way because I don't know how you have named it by yourself)

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin 

class ToolsView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
    # ...

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.groups.filter(name='YourGroupName').exists()
```

---

If you want to use a function-based view instead of class-based, then you can do this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test

@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='YourGroupName').exists())
def my_view(request, pk):
    # ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required    
@method_decorator([
login_required,
permission_required('staff.tools_can_access', reverse_lazy('staff:login'), True)], name='dispatch')
class ToolsView(FormView):
    pass
```

first assign permissions to groups that you made and then change the permission_required args.

it's will be perfect to use generic views